# String Manipulation in C

Tags: c, parsing, string, bnf

I am helping my nephew for his C lab homework, it is a string manipulation assignment and applying Wang's algorithm.

Here is the BNF representation for the input.

```
<s> ::= <l> # <r>

<l> ::= <list>| ε
<r> ::= <list>| ε
<list> ::= <f>|<f> , <list>
<f> ::= <letter>| - <f>| (<f><op><f>)
<op> ::= & | | | >
<letter> ::= A |... | Z
```

What is the best practice to handle and parse this kind of input in C? How can I parse this structure without using `struct`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SO convention is to add `homework` tag for homework :-)

Comment: This is not strictly homework (he is not directly asking for the solution of an exercise), he is asking for best practice and he clearly stated that he is helping his nephew so I think it doesn't require the homework tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to make every rule (or "production") a function.  This is called a "recursive descent" parser.

Write two routine that will peek at and get the next character as well.

This will give you some code that looks something like this (in pseudocode):

```
// <sequent> ::= <lhs> # <rhs>
sequent()
    lhs()
    if peekchar() != '#' then error
    else poundsign = nextchar()
    rhs()


// <lhs> ::= <formulalist>| ε
lhs()
    if peekchar() == EOF
        return
    else
       formula()

// <rhs> ::= <formulalist>| ε
rhs()
    if peekchar() == EOF
        return
    else
       formulalist()

// <formulalist> ::= <formula>|<formula> , <formulalist>
formulalist()
   formula()
   if peekchar() is ','
       comma = nextchar()
       return formulalist()

// <formula> ::= <letter>| - <formula>| (<formula><inﬁxop><formula>)
formula()
    next = peekchar()
    if next in A..Z
        letter
    else if next is -
        minus_sign = nextchar()
        return formula()
    else
        formula()
        infixop()
        formula()

// <inﬁxop> ::= & | | | >
infixop()
    c = nextchar()
    if c not in &,|,> then error

// <letter> ::= A | B | ... | Z
letter()
    c = nextchar()
    if c not A..Z then error
```

and so forth, for each rule.

The general idea:

- each rule is a function
- at certain points the function peeks ahead to see what to do.  for example, formula() checks to see if the first character is a minus sign.

Comment: ε means "empty" not end of file.  Your function for LHS needs to be modified accordingly.  Also, lhs calls fiormula rather than formulalist which , I guess, is a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with some advancements, algorithm works.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have your BNF, the simplest way to parse this kind of input would be to use a parser generator. But due to this being homework, I'm not sure wether using a generator is allowed.

Nevertheless, you can also use a hand-written parser. Just do a search for recursive descent parsers...